# How can I enable seek operations access in a document provider?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, document-provider

I developed a sftp document provider that works quite well. I am using pipes to transfer files using openDocument, it works as long as access to the files is sequential, however I get a `broken pipe` as soon as, for example, I use VLC and jump forward in time.

here is the code for your reference: https://github.com/aguaviva/sftp-documents-provider

Any idea how to fix this?